# Merging of 2 dropdowns into one by concatenating values of a map

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am currently working on a project where I am asked to merge the values of 2 dropdowns and create a new dropdown with concatenated values. One of my suggest a solution to create a observable list which contains the merged values of the dropdowns and create a map which shows the split values of the observed merged value let us say a map with [1.2 -> release='1' and branch = '1.2' ].Here is some code regarding the same.

revisionselection.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Revision } from '../model/revision/revision.model';
import { RevisionService } from '../model/revision/revision.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-revision-selection',
    templateUrl: 'revision-selection.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['revision-selection.component.css'],
})



export class RevisionSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() revisionObservable: string;
    @Input() initializeBlank = false;
    usedRevisionObservable: Observable<Revision>;

    currentRevision: Revision;
    revisionsAsList: Revision[];

    selectableReleases: string[];
    selectedRelease: string;

    selectableBranches: string[];
    selectedBranch: string;

    selectableRevisions: string[];
    selectedRevision: string;

    mergedRevisionList: Revision[];

    constructor(private revisionService: RevisionService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (!this.revisionObservable) {
            this.usedRevisionObservable = this.revisionService.currentRevision;
        } else {
            this.usedRevisionObservable = this.revisionService.getCustomObservable(this.revisionObservable);
        }
        console.log(`subscribing to Observable '${this.revisionObservable}'`);
        this.usedRevisionObservable.subscribe(rev => this.setRevision(rev));
        this.revisionService.getAllRevisions().pipe(delay(1000)).subscribe((revisions: Revision[]) => {
            if (!this.revisionsAsList || this.revisionsAsList.length === 0) {
                this.revisionsAsList = revisions;
                this.setDropdowns(this.revisionService.getSelectables(this.selectedRelease, this.selectedBranch, this.selectedRevision));
            } else {
                this.revisionsAsList = revisions;
            }
            if (!this.initializeBlank && !this.currentRevision && revisions && revisions.length > 0) {
                revisions.sort(Revision.compare).reverse();
                this.setRevision(revisions[0]);
                console.log(`REvSelection of '${this.revisionObservable}' changes revision to ${revisions[0].id}`);
                this.revisionService.changeRevision(revisions[0], this.revisionObservable);
            }
        });
        console.log(`init rev-selection with revision Observable ID: '${this.revisionObservable}'`);
    }

    setRevision(revision: Revision) {
        if (revision) {
            this.currentRevision = revision;
            this.selectedRelease = this.currentRevision.rls;
            this.selectedBranch = this.currentRevision.branch;
            this.selectedRevision = this.currentRevision.revision;
            if (this.revisionsAsList) {
                this.setDropdowns(this.revisionService.getSelectables(this.selectedRelease, this.selectedBranch, this.selectedRevision));
            }
        }
    }

    setDropdowns(dropdownLists: [string[], string[], string[]]) {
        this.selectableReleases = dropdownLists[0].sort().reverse();
        this.selectableBranches = dropdownLists[1].sort().reverse();
        this.selectableRevisions = dropdownLists[2].sort().reverse();
    }

    checkForSelectedRevision() {
        if (this.selectedRelease && this.selectedBranch && this.selectedRevision) {
            this.currentRevision = this.revisionsAsList.find(rev => rev.rls === this.selectedRelease
                                                              && rev.branch === this.selectedBranch
                                                              && rev.revision === this.selectedRevision);
            if (this.currentRevision) {
                this.revisionService.changeRevision(this.currentRevision, this.revisionObservable);
            }
        } else {
            this.currentRevision = undefined;
        }
    }

    setCurrentRelease(chosenRls: string) {
        // console.log('called overview.component.ts setCurrentRls()');
        this.selectedRelease = chosenRls;
        this.setDropdowns(this.revisionService.getSelectables(this.selectedRelease,
                                                              this.selectedBranch,
                                                              this.selectedRevision));
        this.checkForSelectedRevision();
      }
      setCurrentBranch(chosenBranch: string) {
        // console.log('called overview.component.ts setCurrentRls()');
        this.selectedBranch =  chosenBranch;
        this.setDropdowns(this.revisionService.getSelectables(this.selectedRelease,
                                                              this.selectedBranch,
                                                              this.selectedRevision));
        this.checkForSelectedRevision();
      }
      setCurrentRevision(chosenRevision: string) {
        // console.log('called overview.component.ts setCurrentRls()');
        this.selectedRevision = chosenRevision;
        this.setDropdowns(this.revisionService.getSelectables(this.selectedRelease,
                                                              this.selectedBranch,
                                                              this.selectedRevision));
        this.checkForSelectedRevision();
    }

    getComponentName(): string { // hacky solution for prod build
        return 'RevisionSelectionComponent';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropboxes">
    <!-- Dropdown menu for selection via release-->
    <div class="Rls">
        <b>Releases: </b>
            <select [ngModel]="selectedRelease" (ngModelChange)="setCurrentRelease($event)">
                <option></option>
                <option [ngValue]="x" *ngFor="let x of selectableReleases">
                    {{ x }}
                </option>
            </select>
    </div>

   <div class="revision">
        <b>Branch: </b>
            <select [ngModel]="selectedBranch" (ngModelChange)="setCurrentBranch($event)">
                <option></option>
                    <option [ngValue]="x" *ngFor="let x of selectableBranches">
                            {{ x }}
                    </option>
                </select>
    </div> 

    <div class="revision">
        <!-- Dropdown menu for selection via revision-->
        <b>Revision: </b>
        <select [ngModel]="selectedRevision" (ngModelChange)="setCurrentRevision($event)">
            <option></option>
            <option [ngValue]="x" *ngFor="let x of selectableRevisions">
                {{ x }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Revision } from './revision.model';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { NotificationService } from '../../notifications/notifications.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class RevisionService {
  private revisionsUrl = '/api/v1/json/revisions';
  reset = new EventEmitter<any>();


  private revisionSource = new ReplaySubject<Revision>(null);
  public readonly currentRevision = this.revisionSource.asObservable();
  cRevision = new EventEmitter<Revision>();
  public currentBaseRevision = new ReplaySubject<Revision>(null);
  public currentCompareRevision = new ReplaySubject<Revision>(null);

  private _revisionUpdate = new Subject();
  public readonly revisionUpdate = this._revisionUpdate.asObservable();

  // holds BehaviorSubject that are dynamically created by other components
  // like this, we can easily store the last selected revision for each view
  private behaviorSubjectMap = new Map<string, BehaviorSubject<Revision>>();

  // Technically we would have to invalidata this cache based on some heuristic,
  // but as long as they don't keep the tab open for days this should'nt be an issue
  private cachedRevisionList: Revision[];

                                 // rls,branch,revision:  [rls' , branches, revisions]
  private selectionToSelectableCache = new Map<string, [string[], string[], string[]]>();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private notificationService: NotificationService) {
  }



  getRevision(id: number): Observable<Revision> {
    const fullUrl = `${this.revisionsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Revision>(fullUrl);
  }

  getAllRevisions(): Observable<Revision[]> {
    console.log('getAllRevision() called');
    if (this.cachedRevisionList) {
      return Observable.of(this.cachedRevisionList);
    } else {
      console.log('revisionList cache not available.');
      return this.httpClient.get<Revision[]>(this.revisionsUrl).pipe(
        tap( revList => {
        this.cachedRevisionList = revList;
        this.selectionToSelectableCache = new Map<string, [string[], string[], string[]]>();
      }));
    }
  }

  getRevisionSvg(): Observable<string> {
    console.log('getRevisionSvg() called');
    return this.httpClient.get<string>(this.revisionsUrl + '/svg', { responseType: 'text' as 'json' });
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  postNewRevision(xmiFile: string, rls: string, revision: string, branch: string, name: string, description: string, overrideExisting: boolean): Observable<string> {
    console.log('postNewRevision() called');
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('xmiFile', xmiFile);
    formdata.append('rls', rls);
    formdata.append('revision', revision);
    formdata.append('branch', branch);
    formdata.append('name', name);
    formdata.append('description', description);
    formdata.append('overrideExisting', String(overrideExisting));
    return this.httpClient.post<string>(this.revisionsUrl, formdata, { responseType: 'text' as 'json' })
      .do(response => {
        this.notificationService.notify('success', 'Import succeeded',
          'Import of Revision ' + revision + ' succeeded for Release ' + rls + ' and Branch ' + branch );
        this._revisionUpdate.next();
      });
  }

  deleteRevision(revision: Revision): Observable<string> {
    console.log('deleteRevision() called');
    const fullUrl = `${this.revisionsUrl}/${revision.id}`;
    return this.httpClient.delete<string>(fullUrl, { responseType: 'text' as 'json' })
      .do(response => {
        this.notificationService.notify('success', 'Deleted',
        'Delete Revision ' + revision.revision + ' succeeded for Release ' + revision.rls + ' and Branch ' + revision.branch);
        this._revisionUpdate.next();
      });
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the desired {@link BehaviorSubject} from {@linkcode behaviorSubjectMap}.
   * It the specified key does not exist yet, a new BehaviorSubject will be created.
   * @param name Identifyier for the requested {@link BehaviorSubject}
   */
  private getOrCreateReplaySubject(name: string): BehaviorSubject<Revision> {
    const check = this.behaviorSubjectMap.get(name);
    if (check) {
      return check;
    }
    const ret = new BehaviorSubject<Revision>(null);
    this.behaviorSubjectMap.set(name, ret);
    return ret;
  }

  /**
   * Creates or retrieves an Observable for the provided name.
   * In conjunction with {@link chageRevision/2}, this can be used to only inform a specific
   * set of componets about their relevant revision changes.
   * Internally, {@link ReplaySubject}s are used, so Components subscribing later will still recieve the last change.
   * @param name Identifyier for the requested Observable.
   */
  getCustomObservable(name: string): Observable<Revision> {
    return this.getOrCreateReplaySubject(name).asObservable();
  }

  /**
   * Emmits a change-Event with the provided `revision` on the {@link Observable} specified by `customObservableName`.
   * If the specified Observable doesn't exist yet, it will be created. (Might be useful, if the Revision should be set before subsribing)
   * @param revision The {@link Revision} to change to.
   * @param customObservableName The identifier of the {@link Observable} where the change should be emitted.
   */
  changeRevision(revision: (Revision | number), customObservableName?: string): void {
    this.getAllRevisions().subscribe(revs => {
      if (typeof revision === 'number') {
        revision = revs.find(rev => rev.id === revision);
      }
      console.log(`changing revision of observable ${customObservableName} to id ${revision.id}`);
      if (!customObservableName) {
        this.revisionSource.next(revision);
      } else {
        this.getOrCreateReplaySubject(customObservableName).next(revision);
      }
    });
  }

  getSelectables(rls: string, branch: string, revision: string): [string[], string[], string[]] {
    if (rls === undefined) { rls = ''; }
    if (branch === undefined) { branch = ''; }
    if (revision === undefined) { revision = ''; }

    const cache = this.selectionToSelectableCache.get([rls, branch, revision].join(','));
    if (cache) {
        return cache;
    }

    const setParams = Array<[number, string, string]>();
    const unsetParams = Array<[number, string, string]>();
    if (rls !== '') { setParams.push([0, 'rls', rls]);
    } else { unsetParams.push([0, 'rls', rls]); }
    if (branch !== '') { setParams.push([1, 'branch', branch]);
    } else { unsetParams.push([1, 'branch', branch]); }
    if (revision !== '') { setParams.push([2, 'revision', revision]);
    } else { unsetParams.push([2, 'revision', revision]); }

    const selectablesMap = new Map<string, Set<string>>();
    selectablesMap.set('rls', new Set<string>());
    selectablesMap.set('branch', new Set<string>());
    selectablesMap.set('revision', new Set<string>());

    if (setParams.length === 0) {
        this.cachedRevisionList.forEach(crevision => {
            selectablesMap.get('rls').add(crevision.rls);
            selectablesMap.get('branch').add(crevision.branch);
            selectablesMap.get('revision').add(crevision.revision);
        });

    } else  {
        this.cachedRevisionList.forEach(crevision => {
            let skip = false;
            for (const setParam of setParams) {
                if (crevision[setParam[1]] !== setParam[2]) {
                    skip = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!skip) {
                for (const unsetParam of unsetParams) {
                    selectablesMap.get(unsetParam[1]).add(crevision[unsetParam[1]]);
                }
            }
        });
        for (const setParam of setParams) {
            selectablesMap.get(setParam[1]).add(setParam[2]);
            // calculate selectables for the already set ones by emulating that the set parameter is not set
            const paramList = [rls, branch, revision];
            paramList[setParam[0]] = '';
            this.getSelectables(paramList[0], paramList[1], paramList[2])[setParam[0]].forEach(sel => {
                selectablesMap.get(setParam[1]).add(sel);
            });
        }
    }

    const selectableReleases = Array.from(selectablesMap.get('rls'));
    selectableReleases.sort();
    const selectableBranches = Array.from(selectablesMap.get('branch'));
    selectableBranches.sort();
    const selectableRevisions = Array.from(selectablesMap.get('revision'));
    selectableRevisions.sort().reverse();
    const returnTuple: [string[], string[], string[]] = [selectableReleases, selectableBranches, selectableRevisions];
    this.selectionToSelectableCache.set([rls, branch, revision].join(','), returnTuple);
    return returnTuple;
}
}
```

Comment: Too much code to read and understand whats going on but if we consider the requirement of merging two dropdown values that means merging two arrays which you can easily achieve by merging two different arrays and create a new one to use in the dropdown.

Comment: In the revision.ts (second ts file below html file), start from the getSelectables function and then check the other files.